# AngularJS animate navigation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have a HTML mockup like this

```
<div id="headbar" ng-swipe-left="ToogleMenu()">
  <div id="menu" ng-hide="menuTogglestate">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      ....
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I access in my controler in the Togglemenu function the #menu point or call a ng-animation I refer to menu in the mockup? Or do I have to add the animation on top of ng-hide from #menu? As I have a jQuery background, I'm a bit lost with the way AngularJS animations are working. But I don't want to use jQuery at all otherwise I will never lear Angular the right way. Just for the record, I would like to use javascript and not css keyframe animations.

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger `ToogleMenu()` on swipe left and change `menuTogglestate` to `false` then display `#menu`?

Comment: No, I know how this works, but I want on show and on hide to animate the menu with a slide effect like go from left -200 to left :0 and then from 0 back to -200 if you need to hide

Comment: So you want to slide out menu when `ToogleMenu()` is called but this has nothing to do with `ng-hide="menuTogglestate"`?

Comment: I want to bind it to the show and hide parameter as shown here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow#usage_animations but with javascript animation and not css keyframe animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your module variable is `app`

```
app.animation('#menu', function() {
  return {

    beforeAddClass : function(element, className, done) {
      if(className == 'ng-hide') {
        jQuery(element).animate({left: -200}, done);
      }
      else {
        done();
      }
    },

    removeClass : function(element, className, done) {
      if(className == 'ng-hide') {
        jQuery(element).css({left: -200}).animate({left: 0}, done);
      }
      else {
        done();
      }
    }

  };
});
```

Comment: So I need jQuery to do the job?

Comment: @Johnny000 yes, you need some DOM manipulation library to do the job.